# jQuery Animation along a circular path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an UI with jQuery animation. The goal is to have a circular menu and when we click on a link an object follows the external path of the circular menu. 
um.. not clear ? Let me show you my fiddle:

This is my first attempt:

[Fiddle one](http://jsfiddle.net/2mhynskz/7/)

```
function driveTo(new_value){
  pre_value = document.getElementById("pre_value").value;
  var arc_params = {
      center: [180,180],
      radius: 180,
      start: pre_value,
      end: new_value,
      dir: -1
   }
$(".car").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)})
document.getElementById("pre_value").value = new_value;
```

}

**This attempt presents a problem.. If the green dot is at, let's say 90 and you click on 270 it gets crazy for some reasons that I don't understand. But then still stops at the correct position ?!**

And my second:

[Fiddle two](http://jsfiddle.net/2mhynskz/6/)

```
function driveTo(new_value){
  pre_value = document.getElementById("pre_value").value;

  // catch if the new position is bigger than the previous one
  if (new_value > pre_value) {
    var arc_params = {
            center: [180,180],
               radius: 180,
               start: pre_value,
               end: 0,
               dir: -1
            }
      $(".car").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)})
    var arc_params = {
            center: [180,180],
               radius: 180,
               start: 0,
               end: new_value,
               dir: -1
            }
      $(".car").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)})
  }
  else{
    var arc_params = {
            center: [180,180],
               radius: 180,
               start: pre_value,
               end: new_value,
               dir: -1
            }
      $(".car").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)})
  }

document.getElementById("pre_value").value = new_value;
```

}

**In this one I try to catch the problem I encouter in the first proposition by checking if the new value is bigger than the previous one. If true the object has to go to the position 0 first and then continue to the new value.**

But the problem with this is that obiouvsly the object decreases his speed when it reaches zero and then accelerate again to reach the original goal.

And I think it's not really nice.. I wish I could avoid that !

I am using the [jQuery arc path plugin](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) and there is very little documentation about it..

Any suggestions ?

**UPDATE**

Here is a [better fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mhynskz/9/) with an real linear speed based on the distance the shape has to travel. And there is even a speedFactor that you can set :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand *why* the craziness is happening, but here are some workarounds:

1. If you can tolerate going counter-clockwise, you can just remove the `dir` param, or set it to `dir: 1` and it seems to "behave".
2. If you just want the shortest distance regardless of direction, you could do something like:

   ```
   var value_sub = pre_value - new_value;
   var which_dir = value_sub == 90 || value_sub == -270 ? -1 : 1;
   ```

   then set `dir: which_dir` in the params.  This seems to avoid the craziness.
3. If you must have clockwise (and I'm guessing you might, since you have `dir` set to -1 all your examples), you could use your two-animation work-around (clever, BTW) and avoid the slow-down at 0 by overriding [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)'s default "easing" setting, which is "swing".  For example, at http://jsfiddle.net/2mhynskz/8/, I've changed your animations to look like

   ```
   $(".car").animate({path : new $.path.arc(arc_params)},400,"linear")
   ```

   I just used 400 since it's apparently the default duration setting.  (Of course, you could make that variable too, if you wanted it to appear to have a constant velocity.)  If you still need a swing-like effect, you could probably fake it by making the second .animate()'s duration longer.

Comment: I just realized that having traversals of different lengths, sometimes done twice, each at 400 ms, will produce uneven easing anyway, so you'd probably need to make 400 variable depending on the particular traversal.

Comment: Great, helps a lot !!! And yeah I have to use option number 3 because my animation is a car :)

Comment: I will work on a more stable way to get a real linear animation effect and post the final answer.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could be of some help (I'm just blown away that such a plugin exists). I wonder if your original problem might warrant a bug report on the plugin's GitHub page. Currently too tired to investigate whether such behavior is actually a _feature_, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I've made a plugin for that. It is called [jQuery Vortex](http://vortex.montezuma.it/).

I did not use the arc path plugin or any other plugin, so my approach is probably different. Here is the snippet of code where the elements are equally positioned around the circle (or the ellipse):

```
            originalKidsSize[i] = {
                width: $(this).width(),
                height: $(this).height()
            };

            var kidHalfHeight = $(this).height() / 2;
            var kidHalfWidth = $(this).width() / 2;

            var kidPositions = [];

            for (var j = 0; j < positionsCount; j += 1) {

                kidPositions.push({
                    top: ((1 + Math.sin(offsetPosition + (j / radiantFactor))) * vortexHalfHeight) - kidHalfHeight,
                    left: vortexHalfWidth * (1 + Math.cos(offsetPosition + (j / radiantFactor))) - kidHalfWidth
                });

            }

            var positionIndex = i * Math.round(positionsCount / kids.length);

            kidsPositionIndexes[i] = positionIndex;

            var radiantVariable = (Math.sin(offsetPosition + positionsRadiants[positionIndex]) * settings.deepFactor);
            var resizeFactor = (1 + radiantVariable);

            var newWidth = originalKidsSize[i].width * resizeFactor;
            var newHeight = originalKidsSize[i].height * resizeFactor;

            $(this)
                .css({
                    "width": newWidth,
                    "height": newHeight,
                    "top": kidPositions[positionIndex].top - ((newHeight - (originalKidsSize[i].height)) / 2),
                    "left": kidPositions[positionIndex].left - ((newWidth - (originalKidsSize[i].width)) / 2),
                    "z-index": 200 + Math
                        .round(100 * (Math
                            .sin(offsetPosition + positionsRadiants[positionIndex])))
                });
```

At the time CSS3 hardware-accelerated transitions were not mature across different browsers, so CSS2 transitions are applied.

Feel free to try to integrate CSS3 transitions: here is the [link at the github repository](https://github.com/monteiz/jquery-vortex).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, added some more information and the snippet of code relevant to the question.